# Can I refresh Excel queries without signing in to VM?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, windows-server

I am looking to automate the query refresh for a macro-enabled Excel file (Office 365 Excel 16.0) on a Windows Server VM. The connections are queries to a MySQL database. However, this is for a daily refresh that I'd like to schedule and not have to sign in to the VM for the refresh to succeed.

I have tried using a Python script, VBA macro, and AutoHotkey script alongside Windows Task Scheduler, but it looks like Excel requires the user to be signed in to the machine for a refresh to occur.

Is there a workaround to schedule a refresh of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Could the question perhaps be phrased as how to schedule tasks independent of user signon?

I also face the lack of scheduling of Excel queries as an issue, however without a macro.

Have you tried any of the following?

- Windows scheduler that runs on a remote desktop
- An RPA ("external macro") that opens, waits, saves and closes the Excel files containing queries to be updated
- ETL tool like SQL Server Integration Services

Comment: Windows scheduler on a remote desktop works, but is a last resort. This has given me issues in the past with logging itself out randomly, despite settings to the contrary.

AutoHotkey is an RPA I've used, but the query update fails without the user being logged in.

And unfortunately, our cybersecurity team won't allow SSIS or other ETL programs.

Comment: Is it perhaps because the RPA has not been granted access to the database?

Comment: Given that I'm seeing the same issue of not refreshing when using VBA + Windows Task Scheduler, and Python + Task Scheduler, I think it's an issue of Excel needing to be "visible" (by that, I mean it can't operate outside of its UI, and therefore needs the user signed in).

Comment: by the way have you tried Power Query and/or Power BI?